# django oauth toolkit unsupported_grant_type error

Tags: django, oauth

I tried to add outh2 to my django app, so I used django oauth toolkit.
So I followed the tutorial, but if I try to get the users token it always sends me a unsupported_grant_type error. How can I fix this error?

settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'oauth2_provider.contrib.rest_framework.OAuth2Authentication',
    )
}

OAUTH2_PROVIDER = {
    # parses OAuth2 data from application/json requests
    'OAUTH2_BACKEND_CLASS': 'oauth2_provider.oauth2_backends.JSONOAuthLibCore',
}
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include('myapp.api.urls')),
    path('o/', include('oauth2_provider.urls', namespace='oauth2_provider')),
]
```

client type: confidential

authorization grant type:  Resource owner password-based

[chrome advanced rest client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hktyp.png)

url : http://client_id:client_secret@localhost:8000/o/token/

requirements.txt

```
asgiref==3.2.5
autopep8==1.5
certifi==2019.11.28
chardet==3.0.4
Django==3.0.4
django-oauth-toolkit==1.3.0
djangorestframework==3.11.0
idna==2.9
oauthlib==3.1.0
pycodestyle==2.5.0
pytz==2019.3
requests==2.23.0
sqlparse==0.3.1
urllib3==1.25.8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the **OAUTH2_BACKEND_CLASS** in the **OAUTH2_PROVIDER** settings.

```
OAUTH2_PROVIDER = {
    # parses OAuth2 data from application/json requests
    # 'OAUTH2_BACKEND_CLASS': 'oauth2_provider.oauth2_backends.JSONOAuthLibCore',
    # this is the list of available scopes
    'SCOPES': {'read': 'Read scope', 'write': 'Write scope', 'groups': 'Access to your groups'}
}
```

If you intend to use the **OAUTH2_BACKEND_CLASS**, you should send the body in **JSON** format.

```
{
    "grant_type":"password",
    "client_id":"<client_id>",
    "client_secret":"<client_secret>",
    "username":"<usename>",
    "password":"<password>"
}
```

```
curl -X POST -d '{"grant_type":"password","client_id":"<client_id>","client_secret":"<client_secret>","username":"<username>","password":"<password>"}' http://localhost:8000/o/token/
```

Answer (score 0):

**1. you have to create application :**

```
http://localhost:8000/o/applications/
```

Click on the link to create a **new application** and fill the form with the following data:

*Name :* just a name of your choice

*Client Type :* confidential

*Authorization Grant Type :* Resource owner password-based
and you give **clientId** and **SecretClient**

**2. Get your token and use your API**

```
curl -X POST -d "grant_type=password&username=<user_name>&password=<password>" -u"<client_id>:<client_secret>" http://localhost:8000/o/token/
```

example:

```
curl -X POST -d "grant_type=password&username=Alex&password=Won123" -u"cWS5WudFiBhHh6BZxcaOgRGfrZjhcP2rfQcWVyaU:puNJ1SgQbp39Ai1TmYJx0wL9LnC6FNarnY3dgYBA3Z7AgQR5zRcfw5U144zxJ6vndW0jtV4WWKip33kQnFUl4v73xt2IosLGHo7k1w35R7aK8aFL3ZBoMcQ3pyaWjkBT" http://127.0.0.1:8000/o/token/
```

The user_name and password are the credential of the users registered in your  Authorization server and finally in response you give token and use token like this for your request :

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer <your_access_token>" http://localhost:8000/api/users
```

pay attention for your application config and your user name and password.

Comment: I tried it again from the beginning and followed your steps, but it still doesn't work...

Comment: I followed https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rest-framework/getting_started.html this tutorial

Comment: check your username and password and your application config again, certainly, your project setting is correct and pay attention your confidential accurately.